# How to show and hide an <option> per a dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if there is a way of hiding an option in a dropdown following the selected answer of another dropdown. I tried to do it like this but it didn't work. THANK YOU!

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" id="band_pma_class">
  <label for="band_pma_id">Band (PMA)</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="band_pma_id" name="band_pma">
    <option value="" selected                 > Select </option>
    <option value="four_pma" id="hide_pma_id" > B4     </option>
    <option value="five_pma"                  > B5     </option>
    <option value="six_pma"                   > B6     </option>
    <option value="seven_pma"                 > B7     </option>
  </select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function disableBand(answer) {
  console.log(answer.value);
  if (answer.value == 1 || answer.value == 4) {
    document.getElementById('hide_pma_id').setAttribute('hidden');
  }
}
```

Comment: there is no way for hidding an option element from a select. You have to remove it. you can also use a disabled attribute

Comment: but I want, for example, to select a country and then according to the user's selection define the options for the next dropdown. Is it possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible, but not with a "hidding" method

Comment: see a sample there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71774127/declaring-array-within-variable-for-cascading-dropdown-javascript/71774389#71774389

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a two sets of data - one to hold the first select options, the second that acts as a dictionary where each key is a country name, and its value is an array of options you want to add to the second select.

Add a change listener to the first select. When it's fired create a list of new options in the second select using the value from the select to lookup the options in the dictionary.

```js
// Set up an array of countries, and an object with those
// countries as keys - their values will be whatever you want
// the second select updated with
const countries = ['Sweden', 'Norway', 'Germany'];
const options = { sweden: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['1', '2', '3']], norway: [['e', 'f', 'g'],['4', '5', '6']], germany: [['h', 'i', 'j'],['7', '8', '9']] };

// Initialise the country
const country = 'sweden';

// Cache the selects
const countriesSelect = document.querySelector('#countries');
const lettersSelect = document.querySelector('#letters');
const numbersSelect = document.querySelector('#numbers');

// Add a change listener to the country select
countriesSelect.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

// Initialise the select options
countriesSelect.innerHTML = createOptions(countries);
updateLettersSelect(country);

// Get the value from the changed select
function handleChange(e) {
  const { value } = e.target;
  updateLettersSelect(value);  
}

// Update the second select with the values from
// the dictionary
function updateLettersSelect(value) {
  lettersSelect.innerHTML = createOptions(options[value][0]);
  numbersSelect.innerHTML = createOptions(options[value][1]);
}

// Create some options
function createOptions(data) {
  return data.map(option => {
    return `
      <option value="${option.toLowerCase()}">
        ${option}
      </option>`;
  });
}
```

```html
<select id="countries"></select>
<select id="letters"></select>
<select id="numbers"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you!! Is there a way to have 3 selects? For example: when I choose the country automatically impacts 2 other selects, not just one as the code sent by you. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sure. You could, for example, use a nested array in options for each property: `sweden: [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]],...`. Then assign `options[country][0]` to the second select, and `options[country][1]` to the third select. @LeticiaGisele

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow you now :(

Comment: @LeticiaGisele I've updated the answer two include an additional select. In options each property value is a nested array. The second select receives the array at `options[value][0]`, the third the array at `options[value][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a *css* **class** that styles the *nested **option*** element to `display: none` and basically toggle the class using `el.classList.add('classname')` or `el.classList.remove('classname')` depending on the value the user changes in the select.

- You will also need to check if the value of the second drop down is set to a restricted value prior to the user selecting the first value that then restricts it from being seen in DOM and then sets it to a restricted value ***(1 or 4)***. In this case the second *selects **value*** will need to be reset to an empty value, ***your default setting*** => `value=''`.

*If this is not what you were looking for, let me know and I can further adjust my answer or remove it.*

```js
function disableBand(answer) {
  if (parseInt(answer.value) !== '') {
    if (parseInt(answer.value) === 1 || parseInt(answer.value) === 4) {
      document.getElementById('hide_pma_id').classList.add('hidden')
      document.getElementById('band_pma_id').value = ''
    } else {
      document.getElementById('hide_pma_id').classList.remove('hidden')
    }
  } 
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" id="support_class">
  <label for="support_id">CMPA Support Needed</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="support_id" name="support" onchange="disableBand(this)">
    <option value="" selected> Select </option>
    <option value="0"> Both </option>
    <option value="1"> PMA - Financial Management </option>
    <option value="3"> PMO - Project Administration </option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="band_pma_class">
  <label for="band_pma_id">Band (PMA)</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="band_pma_id" name="band_pma">
    <option value="" selected> Select </option>
    <option value="four_pma" id="hide_pma_id"> B4 </option>
    <option value="five_pma"> B5 </option>
    <option value="six_pma"> B6 </option>
    <option value="seven_pma"> B7 </option>
  </select>
```